# Inline Python Code in Sublime Snippets

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, inline-code

Is it possible to write Python(Sublime Text API) in a `.sublime-snippet` file.

Like if I want to grab a value from `.sublime-settings` file and insert it into a snippet.

Example:
File `random.sublime-settings` consists of

```
[
{
  "key1": "value1";
  "key2": "value2"
}
]
```

So if I want to insert "value1" and "value2" in a snippet, how do I do it?, First off is there a way this is even possible?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot execute code with `.sublime-snippet` files. In order to do what you want to do, you'll need to write a [plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html). To execute it, you can either bind a [key combination](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) to it, or create a [macro](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html).